# How to reorder test execution based on dataprovider?

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

Using TestNG @DataProvider will trigger tests in the following order:

Assuming dataprovider returns `{ [0], [1], [2] }`, TestNG runs:

```
test1(0)
test1(1)
test1(2)

test2(0)
test2(1)
test2(2)
...
```

Is there any way to trigger the tests to run in this order?

```
test1(0)
test2(0)

test1(1)
test2(1)

test1(2)
test2(2)
...
```

A thousand thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<suite group-by-instances="true">
```

Comment: Many thanks Cedric!  I found you answer in https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/74    I was using testng V6.2, so update to V6.4 in first place. and I need to add @Factory to meet above request. Finally, I got it work~ Many thanks~!!